# Elasticsearch aggregations - OR in buckets

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Say I have 5 docs:

```json
{
  "owner": "joe",
  "color": "black"
},
{
  "owner": "joe",
  "color": "red"
},
{
  "owner": "joe",
  "color": "blue"
},
{
  "owner": "jack",
  "color": "black"
},
{
  "owner": "jack",
  "color": "white"
}
```

and aggregations:

```json
{
  aggs: {
    owner: {
      "terms": {
        "field": "owner"
      }
    },
    color: {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

to aggregate docs by owner and color.

If I run match all query I got:

```
owner
joe: 3
jack: 2

color
black: 2
red: 1
blue: 1
white: 1
```

What I want to achieve is: if I filter docs by `owner: joe` I want to get 3 docs where `owner` is `joe`, the color aggregation:

```
color
black: 1
red: 1
blue: 1
```

BUT I'd like to get the `owner` aggregation:

```
owner
joe: 3 [selected]
jack: 2 [possible to extend]
```

So get the number of other buckets that can be selected to extend the final result. So something like "OR" between the buckets.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to achieve this is by using a [`post_filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/filter-search-results.html#post-filter). The query below will return:

- only `joe`'s colors (using `filtered_colors`)
- only `joe`'s documents (using `post_filter`)
- all owners that you can filter on (using a `all_owners`)

Query:

```
POST owners/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "filtered_colors": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "owner.keyword": "joe"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "color": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "color.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "all_owners": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "owner.keyword"
      }
    }
  },
  "post_filter": {
    "term": {
      "owner.keyword": "joe"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, that's it, just wanted to write it :) thanks for help guys!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, you want to aggregate on the `owner` as well as `color` (where the `owner` is equal to `joe`) You can use [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) to achieve your required use case -

```json
    {
      "size": 0,
      "aggs": {
        "owner": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "owner.keyword"
          }
        },
        "filtered_aggregation": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "owner": "joe"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "color": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "color.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**Search Result:**

```json
    "aggregations": {
        "owner": {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
          "buckets": [
            {
              "key": "joe",
              "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
              "key": "jack",
              "doc_count": 2
            }
          ]
        },
        "filtered_aggregation": {
          "doc_count": 3,
          "color": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "black",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "blue",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "red",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: I'm not sure this satisfies the constraint `I want to get 3 docs where owner is joe`